# Receiving data with SEND intent create multiple instances of an Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, instance

If I use this [how to](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html) and application is running when data are received from other apps, then a new instance is created instead of using the same. How to prevent this?

I have tried:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

or

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

but then receiving is not working, because then recieved intent is in all cases: **android.intent.action.MAIN**